# Attempt to invoke virtual method java.lang.String.android.content.Context.getPackageName() on null object reference

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have gone through so many git issues and stackoverflow questions but unable to find the exact solution.

I am getting error :

Attempt to invoke virtual method java.lang.String.android.content.Context.getPackageName() on null object reference

I know that it is related to Package where im going to access method of a package but actually unable to access.

Also i dont have any clue that in which file it happened.

Dont know about the exact file, where it is occuring, do let me know if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: it means you have not linked your libraries, first solution is run  "react-native link" , then check all libraies is added to MainApplication.java in getPackages()

Comment: @Nima i have around 40+ libraries, do i need to link all of them one by one ???

Comment: just check which one is not inside getPackages()

Comment: Can you explain me how can i do this, because i have so many libraries

Comment: why you just don't try to run this command "react-native link" and then go for other solutions but before that make sure you have backup from your project

Comment: I have executed command given by you, and packages are linked, but still facing same error, actually im confused like i have package named react-native-loading-spinner-overlay and how can i find and if not than add it ti getPackages()

Comment: I think the package you mentioned doesn't need to link because it's pure javascript library , you need to go inside build.gradle(Module:app) inside your android folder and check if all the projects you have imported in there, are available inside MainApplication file

Comment: can you just share build.gradle and mainApplication file ?

Comment: Where can i share, because content is too much long

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @David, No sir unable to find any feasible solution